# What is the lowest you can get in 2048?

Tags: strategy, 2048-game

What is the lowest score you can get in 2048?  Creating high numbers is obviously bad, but what about not matching numbers?
What is the chance of getting this lowest score?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you were unlucky enough and were not trying...You could in theory end up with a square full of alternating 2s and 4s.  It should even be possible to do this without matching, which means a score of 0.

Comment: I think you'd actively have to try, but I agree it's probably possible.

Comment: Even with actively trying, it also requires a high degree of luck (I have tried. :P )

Comment: It's almost impossible to score 0 unless you are *very* lucky. Starting with two adjacent 2 tiles means your minimum score is 2 already. Having tried a few times, I find it difficult to score below 100.

Comment: I was able to get a 72, but yest [un]luck has a lot to do with it

Comment: @MichaelMyers it is still possible to break up the pair by starting in the orthogonal direction (say, down) and having a 4 spawn under one of them to stack upon.

Comment: @JanDvorak: True, there is a 10% chance of getting a 4 on any given move, so that could happen.

Comment: to be exact, the probability that 8 2's and 8 4's spawn is `0.1^8 * 0.9^8 * (16 choose 8) = 5.5e-5`